# How can I redirect my views correctly with a SQL server Database? (not local database on the computer)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I have created an MVC application in visual studio 2013 using Visual Basic and when the user logs into the application it will either display the log In failed view or continue to the submit Issue view.  All of this was correctly working when I used a local SQL Server database on the machine as it redirected correctly to all views.

But now that I have to publish the application and use an actual live SQL Database Sever not on the machine.  The problem is that it will not redirect to the Submit Issue Page.

The Log In failure HTTP Post will return the Result number 200 (success) but the Submit Issue HTTP Post will return the Result number 302 (redirect Issue).

The application successfully can retrieve information from the live Database because when I compare the Log In details with the details in the Database like this:

```
 Dim userdetailLocal = (From data In usertable.UserTables Where data.username = user.username AndAlso data.userPassword = user.userPassword Select data.username)

If (userdetailLocal.Count() > 0) Then

  Return RedirectToAction("SubmitIssue")

Else
    Return RedirectToAction("LogInFailure")

End If
```

This successfully navigates to either of the options when the details are incorrect or correct.

But only the "LogInFailure" View will successfully return like this:

```
Public Function LogInFailure() As ActionResult
     Return View()
End Function
```

The "submitIssue" view will return this error:

"The page isn't redirecting properly.  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

But the view is basically the same as the other the only difference is that the "submitIssue" view contains other information on it that is required to post an Issue.  The only view that works that contains information required to post information is the "Log In" view.

```
    Public Function SubmitIssue() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function



<HttpPost()>
<AllowAnonymous>
<Authorize>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Public Function SubmitIssue(<Bind(Include:="IssueID,IssueName,IssueSummary")>
                         ByVal issuetable As IssueTable, command As String, objModelMail As IssueTable) As ActionResult

   Return Redirect("Success")
    End Function
```

Then my connection string is:

```
  add name="##connectionString##" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/IssueConnectionString.csdl|res://*/IssueConne ctionString.ssdl|res://*/IssueTracker.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     data source=SERVER\SQLSERVERTEST;
     initial catalog=SERVERDATABASE;
     persist security info=False;
     user id=USER;
     pwd=PWDID;
     integrated security=False;
     workstation id=WORKSTATION;
     packet size=****;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
     App=EntityFramework&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I think it is to do with the permissions of the database but I am not sure does anyone know with I get this redirect error when using the Server Database but not a local database?

I also think that the redirect loop is coming from the browser successfully load the page again and again.  But it cannot actually retrieve the view hence why FireFox is displaying that error message.  The Network tool for the submitIssue view will return the following:

SubmitIssue

```
 302 - POST - LogIn 
 200 - POST - abort?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANC...
 302 - GET - submitIssue
 302 - GET - HttpError500
 302 - GET - NotFound
 302 - GET - NotFound (repeated infinitely)
```

LoginFailure

```
 302 - POST - LogIn
 200 - POST - abort?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANC....
 200 - GET - LogInFailure
 200 - GET - broswerLink
 200 - GET - negotiate?requestURL=http://...
```

Comment: you've got a redirect loop. e.g. page A redirects to page A (self-loop), or a chain of pages (A->B->...->A), and Firefox is detecting that lop. Use your browser's network debug tools to see exactly what the redirect chain is - should give you a hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: I know I have a self loop the problem is that this worked successfully when I was using the local database on the machine with out any self loop.  The when I did use the debug tool the network gave back the Post as 200 (success), then the get submitIssue as 302 (Redirect loop) but only for the one that needed information, so I should not have a redirect loop if it worked using the local database

Comment: @MarcB I don't think it is actually to do with a self-loop because the page says /errors/notFound, and I think the redirect loop is to do with it continuously trying to find the page but unsuccessfully doing this.

Comment: firefox doesn't try to "find pages". it just goes where the `Location` headers tell it to. if it notices that it's looping past the same pages continuously, then you get the warning.

Comment: I think it could be because your SubmitIssue actions are not public. And you should also return a RedirectToAction from your POST method, so this follows the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I added all this information but I still get the same response

Comment: @MarcB  and josh cheers for the help, I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my application working on the server by adding the following information to my application.  The reason why I was getting a redirect loop was because there was a few bits of information missing that I needed to add that prevented the view from being correctly loaded.

In the submitIssue (GET Request) I added these viewbag's information:

```
    ViewBag.issueTypeID = New SelectList(dbServer.IssueTypeTables, "IssueTypeID", "IssueTypeName")
    ViewBag.priorityID = New SelectList(dbServer.PriorityTables, "priorityID", "severity")
```

This allowed the controller to read in the two ID's above which was one of the reasons that it was skipping over the view.

The second thing that I done to solve the issue was to add more information in the submitIssue (POST request).

```
Public Function SubmitIssue(<Bind(Include:="IssueID,IssueSummary,IssueTypeID,priorityID")>
                         issuetable As IssueTable, command As String, objModelMail As IssueTable) As ActionResult
```

Adding both of these to my applications enabled me to get all the views to successfully return Status of 200 (success) and prevent a redirect loop.